# Proof of cyclicity using power of a point

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, power-of-the-point

> An acute-angled triangle $ABC$ is given in the plane. The circle with diameter $AB$ intersects
> altitude $CC'$ and its extension at points $M$ and $N$, and the circle with diameter $AC$ intersects altitude $BB'$ and its extensions at $P$ and $Q$. Prove that the points $M, N, P, Q$ lie on a common circle. (USAMO, 1990)

$MPNQ$ is cyclic if and only if $CBC'B'$ is cyclic. This is because $MPNQ$ is cyclic if and only if $MX\cdot XN=PX\cdot XQ$ by the power of $X$ on the circle whose existence is to be proven. Notice that $B'$ is on the circle with diameter $AB$, because $\angle AB'B=90^{\circ}$, thus $B'X\cdot XB=MX\cdot XN.$

Also, $PX\cdot XQ=CX\cdot XC',$ because $C'$ must be on the circle with diameter $AC$. Therefore, $MX\cdot NX=PX\cdot QX\Longleftrightarrow B'X\cdot XB=CX\cdot XC'$, which happens if and only if $CBC'B'$ is cyclic.

$CBC'B'$ is cyclic. This is because $\angle B'CC'=\angle C'BB'$, since $\triangle ACC'\sim\triangle ABB'.$ Therefore, $MPNQ$ is also cyclic.

I think my solution is likely correct, but my handout gives a different solution, and I'm not very familiar with geometry. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct though it could be made neater.

Let circle with diameter AC be $\omega_C$ and circle with diameter AB be $\omega_B$. As the diameter subtends a right angle on the semicircle, $C'$ lies on $\omega_C$ and $B'$ lies on $\omega_B$.

Now

- Power of orthocenter $X$ wrt $\omega_C$ is $$CX\cdot C'X = PX\cdot QX$$
- Power of orthocenter $X$ wrt $\omega_B$ is $$BX\cdot B'X = MX\cdot NX$$
- Since $$\angle BB'C = 90^{\circ} = \angle BC'C$$ $BC'B'C$ is cyclic.

Power of X wrt circumcircle of $BC'B'C$ is  $$CX\cdot C'X = BX\cdot B'X$$

from which follows $$PX\cdot QX = MX\cdot NX$$

Hence proved, $MPNQ$ is cyclic.